# Postgres SQL ERROR: XX001: invalid page in block

Tags: postgresql, windows-11, postgresql-13

This error has just started popping when I run queries against TABLE_A .......

```
ERROR: XX001: invalid page in block 38 of relation pg_tblspc/16402/PG_14_202107181/16404/125828
```

If I try a very simple query against the same table for example `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A` I get a similar error....

```
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 18446744073709551613 
SQL state: XX000
```

Or another similar query `select count(*) from TABLE_A` gives me....

```
ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 917520
DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_xact/0000": No such file or directory.
SQL state: 58P01
```

Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220344/postgresql-invalid-page-header-in-block) I tried this fix....

```
SET zero_damaged_pages = on;
VACUUM full TABLE_A;
REINDEX TABLE TABLE_A;
```

The 2nd command, VACUUM full TABLE_A produced another related error....

```
ERROR:  found xmax 16384 from before relfrozenxid 379279265 
SQL state: XX001
```

I think all these problems boil down to a simple case of file corruption at the OS level. I do have the ability to drop and re-create this table, but before I start I'd like to know if there's a quicker/simpler solution, and if there's any way of stopping this from happening again.